# Any efficient way to identify a set of 1s in a big array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, while-loop

I have an array called `link_slots` of 800 elements made of `1`, `0` and `-1`.
E.g. `[1 1 1 -1 0 0 0 0 1 1 -1 0 0 1 1 1 1 -1 0 0 ...]`. So, `1` denotes occupied, `0` for unoccupied and `-1`  just to mark the end of a set of 1s.
I want to know the start and end indices of each set of `1`s. E.g.,here, start as `[1,9,14]` and end as `[3,10,17]`. My code works but found out through Profiler that it takes a lot of time. Is there any efficient way to solve this? Considering that I have to do this thing for multiple arrays for size 800 elements.

```
i=1;
while(i<numel(link_slots(1,:)) ) %to cycle through whole array
    j=i
    if(link_slots(1,i)==1)  %i.e. if occupied 
        startt(i)=i %store it in the start array
        j=i
        while(link_slots(index,j+1)~=-1) 
            j=j+1
        end
        endd(i)=j  %store the end index upon encountering -1
    end
    i=j+1
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data= [1 1 1 -1 0 0 0 0 1 1 -1 0 0 1 1 1 1 -1 0 0]';
```

the end indices are very easy to find :

```
I=find(data==-1);
end_indices=I-1;
```

to find the start indices you want the indices of '1' s which previous value is zero or '-1'
so for example:

```
temp=[0;data]; % i added a zero to the start of data to use diff function 
I=find(diff(temp)>0 & data==1) % here diff function calculates difference between subsequent values of array. so in case of your question if we had ..0 1..diff is 1 and ...
```